# How Can I edit the name of a tab in Materializecss?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs, material-design

Hello people from Stackoverflow, I hope you're having a great day. I'm working on a project and I have to use the element tabs from Materializecss framework. Basically I want to achieve the following behavior: the user must be able to edit the name of the tab doing a doble click on the current name. 
This image shows the tabs element: [MATERIALIZE TAB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0so5I.png) 
In this image, you check that there are two tabs, well, I want that by double clicking on the name "NEWFILTER" automatically appears a text box with the current name "newfilter" and the posibility to erase that text and enter a new name. When the user press the enter key automatically the new name has to be placed as the name of the current tab. Do you understand??? How can I do that? Any idea? 
Here is the code of materializecss tab:

```css
.tabs {
border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
      <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#test1">NEWFILTER</a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test2">New Tab</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="test1" class="col s12">BODY TAB 1</div>
    <div id="test2" class="col s12">BODY TAB 2</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The double-click requirement could be kind of annoying. You could try setting the type of your tabs to be [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) if you're okay with having single-clicks.

Otherwise, one general strategy for doing this could be:

1. Create a [contenteditable text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) field that is overlaid on top of the name of the tabs, with the same name as the tabs. Set the display to none by default.
2. Attach an onclick listener to your tabs. Every time the tab is clicked, set a timeout. If the user clicks again within the specified time period, then a double-click happened.
3. If a double-click happened: show the contenteditable text field associated with that tab.
4. Then, the user is able to edit the tab. Attach a keypress eventlistener to the contenteditable text field, to check for if the user has hit "enter".
5. When the user hits enter, get the innerHTML of the editable text field, update the title of the tag, and hide the editable text field.

Comment: could you provide an example code to check your idea please? seems interesting.